# Using string commands with switch() using #define

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm attempting to make use of a `switch()` statement by using keywords instead of an integer. I've written my problem into a more simple and direct example to better point out my goal here. My relevant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define put 0
#define get 1
#define run 2

int main () {
    int ch;

    printf("%s", "Please enter a command: ");
    scanf("%d", ch);

    switch (ch) {
        case 0:
            puts("You chose \"put\" as a command.");
            break;
        case 1:
            puts("You chose \"get\" as a command.");
            break;
        case 2:
            puts("You chose \"run\" as a command.");
            break;
    }
}
```

Ideally, when I scan for user input, I would like the user to be able to utilize the command's provided in the above `#define` statements. Therefore, the user is prompted for a value, `put` is input, and the program outputs the `case 0`. Is this possible with a `switch()`?

Comment: The preprocessor operates on your source code, not on program input.

Comment: Any compiler warnings or errors with `int ch; ... scanf("%d", ch);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a function to convert the user input to your commands.
e.g.

```
int stringToCommand(char* cmd)
{
   if (strcmp(cmd, "put") == 0)
       return put;
   ...
}
```

Then you can use the #defines in the switch

```
int cmd = stringToCommand(userInput);
switch (cmd) {
    case put:
        puts("You chose \"put\" as a command.");
        break;
    ...
```

Normally for this type of scenario I'd look at enums rather than relying on #defines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is shown how the switch statement can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char * key_word[] = { "put", "get", "run" };
    const size_t N = sizeof( key_word ) / sizeof( *key_word );

    enum { PUT, GET, RUN };

    char command[5];

    printf( "Please enter a command: " );
    fgets( command, sizeof( command ), stdin );

    command[ strcspn( command, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < N && strcmp( command, key_word[i] ) != 0 ) i++;

/*  
    if ( i != N )
    {
        printf( "You chose \"%s\" as a command.\n", key_word[i] );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Invalid input." );
    }
*/

    switch ( i )
    {
    case PUT:
        printf( "You chose \"%s\" as a command.\n", key_word[i] );
        break;
    case GET:
        printf( "You chose \"%s\" as a command.\n", key_word[i] );
        break;
    case RUN:
        printf( "You chose \"%s\" as a command.\n", key_word[i] );
        break;
    default:
        puts( "Invalid input." );
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Please enter a command: get
You chose "get" as a command.
```